# How do I split a string into sentences whilst including the punctuation marks?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, punctuation, sentence

I want the split sentences to include the punctuation marks (ex: ?, !, .) and if there's a double quotation mark at the end of the sentence, I want to include that as well.

I used the re.split() function in python3 to get my string to split into sentences. But sadly, the resulting strings don't include the punctuation marks nor do they include the double quotation mark if one is present at the end of the sentence.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
x = 'This is an example sentence. I want to include punctuation! What is wrong with my code? It makes me want to yell, "PLEASE HELP ME!"'
sentence = re.split('[\.\?\!]\s*', x)
```

The output I get is:

```
['This is an example sentence', 'I want to include punctuation', 'What is wrong with my code', 'It makes me want to yell, "PLEASE HELP ME', '"']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting on a lookbehind:

```
sentences = re.split('(?<=[\.\?\!])\s*', x)
print(sentences)

['This is an example sentence.', 'I want to include punctuation!',
 'What is wrong with my code?', 'It makes me want to yell, "PLEASE HELP ME!"']
```

This regex trick works by splitting when we *see* a punctuation symbol immediately behind us.  In this case, we also match and *consume* any whitespace in front of us, before we continue down the input string.

Here is my mediocre attempt to deal with the double quote problem:

```
x = 'This is an example sentence. I want to include punctuation! "What is wrong with my code?"  It makes me want to yell, "PLEASE HELP ME!"'
sentences = re.split('((?<=[.?!]")|((?<=[.?!])(?!")))\s*', x)
print filter(None, sentences)

['This is an example sentence.', 'I want to include punctuation!',
 '"What is wrong with my code?"', 'It makes me want to yell, "PLEASE HELP ME!"']
```

Note that it correctly splits even sentences which end in double quotes.

Comment: Sorry I had a bracket in front of "re" so you have it in your code as well. Please edit it out. As for the result, everything works besides the double quotation mark at the end of the string. Did you run yours? It worked for you? For me the quotation mark shows up as a separate element in the resultant list.

Comment: @investigate311 [I didn't have that problem](https://rextester.com/IQLX27378).  We can adjust my answer to deal with double quotes.

Comment: The updated double quote version works for me! I cleaned up the None and empty strings with a loop.